# Trying to put formData header to an axios post to upload it later on

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, form-data

So this is my code and im trying to post a file to a url but i have no idea what i'm doing wrong..

const onFileUpload = () => {

```
// Create an object of formData
const formData = new FormData();

// Update the formData object
formData.append(
  'file',
  selectedimage,
);

// Details of the uploaded file
console.log(selectedimage);

// Send formData object
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/upload", formData)
  .then(res => { 
    console.log(res.statusText)
  })
```

};

404 is not the problem i will fix it later on.

Im trying to get a formdata header

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i believe the Form Data which i expected it to show in Headers tab is in Payload tab now. Maybe it's some kind of update. This might help newbs like me.